# Cannot use import modules in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm having trouble importing modules into Jupyter notebook. The sys.path is wrong and I don't know how to repair it.

From Jupyter `sys.executable`runs:

```
'/usr/----/opt/python/bin/python2.7'
```

From the command line it runs:

```
'/Users/----/miniconda2/bin/python'
```

so when I try running `import MySQLdb`, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-dd22983d5391> in <module>()
----> 1 import MySQLdb

ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

However, within my command line my import module works fine. How do i remedy this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

install the module `sudo pip install mysql-python`else,

You should try `conda install ipykernel --name Python`, `python -m ipykernel install`. Then it wil fix the notebook it will be seeing your Python kernel. Then create a new `>Python notebook`

Comment: The OP presumably already installed that module in their `miniconda` set-up. This doesn't solve the problem.